# Can Tidyverse 'Mutate' function be used to thin temporal data

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate, temporal

My problem is as follows:

I am using the 'Overlap' package to observe predator-prey interactions of Feral cats vs all other animals.

I am using data obtained from camera traps left out for a few months. The camera's where set to take photo's every 30 seconds when there was movement in front of them.

I need to remove all instances where a particular animal (eg: Cats) occurs more than once within an hour period. If all the instances are counted we might be counting the same animal and accidentally inflating the data.

The problem I have is I don't know how to delete all that occur within the same hour with reference to the last sighting. I don't need to delete all duplicates within say 1 am or 2 am, but need to delete all duplicates within the same hour period in reference to the last one (eg: sighting at 1:50 am and 2:01 am would be the same animal).

Wondering if anyone has any idea's of how to achieve this. Should I use the 'Lubridate' package or the Tidyverse package?

Much appreciated!

Comment: Hi, what is a "duplicate during 1 hour". Is that transitive ? Ie if one case occurs at 1 am, one at 1 am 35, one at 2 am 20, one at 3am, are they all connected ?

Comment: Hello, the idea is that if a given species is recorded twice within one hour, it is likely the same animal. I am trying to only count each individual animal and not duplicate them which would inflate the data set artificially for my purpose. 

So if an animal of a particular species is sited at 1:01 am, 1:10 am and 1:15 am and the next record is at 2:54 am, I want to be able to collect the point at 1:01 am and 2:54 am but remove the points of 1:10 am and 1:15 am.

Comment: Hi, you've not answered to my question : is your relation transitive ? What happen if you have regular points every 5 minutes between 1 am and 4 am ?

Comment: Hello, it is not transvestite. Each point is random. There are no regular points or patterns in the data set.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer using igraph and lubridate. As you seem not to have understood the sense of "transitive", I've made as if you've told your relation is transitive (which is **necessary** because otherwise you can't define equivalence classes). Transitive is relative to the relation "same animal if interval is less than 1 hour" not to the data.

So I make a graph, defined by the relation "less than 1 hour inbetween", I compute the components of that graph with igraph, that define equivalence classes in which I select the first elements datewise.

```
library(igraph)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(1L)
df <- data.frame(date=sample(seq(as.POSIXct('2017/01/01'),
                                 as.POSIXct('2017/05/01'),
                                 by="15 mins"),
                             1000),
                 animal=sample(c("Gorilla",
                                 "Parrot",
                                 "Fox"),1000,replace = TRUE),
                 value=rnorm(1000))

is_same_hour <- sapply(df$date,function(x) as.integer(abs(as.duration(x %--% df$date)) <
                                                        duration(1,"hour")))

is_same_animal <- sapply(df$animal,function(x) as.integer(x == df$animal),USE.NAMES = FALSE)

adjacency_matrix <- is_same_hour * is_same_animal

df$group <- components(graph_from_adjacency_matrix(adjacency_matrix,mode = "upper"))$membership
```

What you obtain in the group variable, this way, is a vector with equal ints for each observation.

Then, if you (by example) order by date, you can then use !duplicated if you only want to keep the first animal, datewise.

```
df <- df[order(df$date),]
df <- df[!duplicated(df$group),]
```

Comment: ps : next time, it would be very useful if you provided a sample of data (like my df)

Comment: Hello,

Thank you so much for your help! Yes- I do not really understand most of what you are asking/saying. 

Here is an example of what we have come up with so far: 
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/16Kwj63TPEWi7SuavcwUCokImcHDH8gYO?usp=sharing&fbclid=IwAR3jefo8qjdQ2C6EMNrkirhPidLy2t_2GzIZm-Xx6K1Z0n0ahgf9TuPmr9g

and

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1BBiT6l8YBzFkGXtVvyK4wBpBpDt5acqd?usp=sharing&fbclid=IwAR3J_1ANIBNzKX5ol1pUHYCpVx0fVO_RQLI7DZ1fyvhSfHtANvTCjkYZh9g

Sorry to link you to a google collab, I don't know how to add code into this site

Comment: Hi @Papp_i . External code is not the stack overflow way. Better select the minimal code that gives you problems, paste it while editing your question, select it and hold CTRL+K

Comment: @Papp_i I've edited my code to include animal species into the relation. It answers your question and I can't do more.